# Validating empty columns with pandas_schema

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, validation, schema

I am using python 3.7 and Pandas_schema trying to generate a validation warnings for any CSV columns that are empty. I am able to successfully run the code, but no warnings are being returned.

This is what I have so far:

```
from io import StringIO
from pandas_schema import Column, Schema
from pandas_schema.validation_warning import ValidationWarning

schema = Schema([
    Column('Test_Column1', allow_empty=False),
    Column('Test_Column2', allow_empty=False),

])

test_data = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''Test_Column1,Test_Column2
test_data1, ''')) # Showing empty column for Test_Column2

errors = schema.validate(test_data)

for error in errors:
    print(error)
```

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems to be a bug with the library that you are using. I tried it with the sample code in the `README` file (modifying it to show the columns) and it didn't work with some inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> allow_empty – True if an empty column is considered valid. False if we
> leave that logic up to the Validation

so I guess that if you set allow_empty to False, the validators - which you did not pass as an argument - determine whether it is validated as true or false. Since there are no validators there is no validation error

https://multimeric.github.io/PandasSchema/